# Rails validation / scope on 24 hour period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, models

I'm trying to put a validation on a record.  The validation will check that the record can't be created if the ip_address and post_id are the same.  This works good.

I am trying to add another condition that will allow this duplication only if it is after a 24 hour period,  if so, allow it to save, but all future saves will be disabled again until the 24 period is over.

Here has been my best attempt so far:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :ip_address, scope: :impressionable_id,
   conditions: -> {where('created_at < ?', Time.now - 24.hours)}
```

So the validation should somehow only check the "latest" record of the group it finds to do the validation to be accurate

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to just make an explicit validator method for this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :ip_address_uniqueness, on: :create

  # ...

  def ip_address_uniqueness
    existing = Foo.where(impressionable_id: self.impressionable_id)
                  .where(ip_address: self.ip_address)
                  .where(created_at: Time.current.all_day)
    errors.add(:ip_address, 'cannot be used again today') if existing
  end

end
```